# Validating lenght of digits and number

Tags: c, validation, char, int, type-conversion

I have been struggling with a project, so i have to validate a number of 4 digits in C, i thought about using chars since i need to validate 0001 but no 1. Then i guess i need to convert that into a integer to work with it. Can someone help me?

```
printf("Enter a number 0 to end:");
gets(str);
while (strcmp(str, "0"))
{
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    flag = 0;
    while (*(cad + j)) {
        if (!isdigit(*(cad + j))) 
            flag = 1;
        j++;
        k = ++;
    }

    if (!flag && k == 4) {
        i = atoi(cad); 
        q = newnode();
        q->num = i;
        stack(&pi,q);
    }
    else
        printf("Wrong number");
    printf("Enter a number 0 to end:");
    gets(str);
}
```

Comment: Yor code was unreadable. And do not use `gets()` it's deprecated. Did you read what `strcmp()` does?

Comment: this part `i need to validate 0001 but no 1.` is unclear for me. can you give us an example that shows where it should fail and where it should success

Comment: if you enter 1 should be invalid if you enter 0001 shoudl be valid thats why i use a string of char to validate number by number

Comment: But is this a general validation rule or is `0001` the only valid value? If it is so you want to check that it has 4 characters and it's a number?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int 
is_valid_number(const char *const string, int *value)
{
    char *endptr;
    *value = strtol(string, &endptr, 10);
    return (((endptr - string) == 4) && (*endptr == '\0'));
}

int 
main(void)
{
    int value;
    const char *string = "001";
    if (is_valid_number(string, &value) != 0)
        fprintf(stdout, "it's valid: %d\n", value);
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "\033[31mINVALID\033[0m\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `is_valid_number("    0",...)`, `is_valid_number("-123",...)` will pass.

Comment: @chux good observation, but lets see if the OP can work it out from here ... Because a simple `if ( ... < 0)` would do.

Answer (score 0):

OP on the right track  (aside from `gets()`)

```
char str[50];
fputs("Enter a number 0 to end:", stdout);

while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL)) {
  str[strcspn(str,"\n")] = '\0';  // lop off potential trailing \n
  if (strcmp(str, "0") == 0) {
    break;
  }
  #define N 4
  int all_digits = 1;
  for (int j = 0; j<N; j++) {
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char) str[j])) {
      all_digits = 0;
      break;
    }
  }   
  if (all_digits && str[N] == '\0')  {
    i = atoi(str); 
    ...
    }
  else
    fputs("Wrong number", stdout);
    ...
```